# Recursive memoized function when adding squared numbers

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm struggling with constructing a momoized recursive function in C#

What I want is to find the sum of squares for n numbers.
What I want to memoize is an already found result of a number squared.
So in n numbers, if I have 3 instances of 2, I want to store (2 * 2) = 4 and not call the function
recursively again to calculate (2 * 2), just return 4 and added it the sum. My function is below.

In playing around wiht the function, what keeps happening is that mem.Add(arr[index], calc); gives
me an exception saying key already exists in mem collection or it does not cycle through all
values in the array. Is this possible, and if so how?

```
int total = 16;
Hashtable mem = new Hashtable();

int[] arr = new int[7];
arr[0] = 2;
arr[1] = 3;
arr[2] = 2;
arr[3] = 4;
arr[4] = 3;
arr[5] = 2;
arr[6] = 4;

public int doSum(int[] arr, Hashtable mem, int index)
{
    int sum = 0;

    if (index < 0)
        return 0;
    if (mem.ContainsKey(arr[index]))
        return (int)mem[arr[index]];
    else
        calc = doSum(arr, mem, index - 1) + (int)Math.Round(Math.Pow(arr[index], 2));

    mem.Add(arr[index], calc);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this - the time taken to save & search for repeated calculations like that is most likely longer than to repeat the calculation.

Comment: It's for a theoretical purpose, rather than a practical one. I'm learning about recursion now, dynamic programming and various programming techniques.

Comment: Code that you provided doesn't compile

Comment: Most likely does not compile for you because the code before the function declaration has to go into a main function which then calls the doSum function.

Comment: @SmokerJones There is no `calc` delcaration in code

Comment: You should learn how to use braces when programming

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Don't use a `Hashtable` use a `Dictionary<int, int>` instead.

Comment: @MartinLiversage - The example code is mapping a number to a number. The generic type for this is a dictionary. A `HashSet<T>` doesn't provide mapping of one value to another.

Comment: @Sean: You are right. I didn't look closely at the code. Just the that `Hashtable` was used as a set of integers. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the exception is that you are always adding the number you are squaring as a key in your Hashtable - it should only be saved if it is not found. Also you are not updating the sum & if you were, then also saving the sum to date, rather than the squared value, so you function would have been wrong as well - try something like this :

```
public int doSum(int[] arr, Hashtable mem, int index)
{
  int sum = 0;

  if (index < 0)
    return 0;

   int sqVal;
   if (mem.ContainsKey(arr[index]))
     sqVal = (int)mem[arr[index]];
   else
   {
     sqVal = (int)Math.Round(Math.Pow(arr[index], 2));
     mem.Add(arr[index], sqVal);
   }

   sum = doSum(arr, mem, index - 1) + sqVal;
   return sum;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I see now. This makes sense. Thanks.